# Does asp.net 4.0 webforms have url and form databinding?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-4.0

I am not sure what this is called. If know know what it's called you can edit this post.

asp.net mvc allows you to do this:

```
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection fc)
{
     Item.Add(fc);
     return View();
}
```

It is nice that in MVC the FormCollection object is automatically populated with the relevant data. Is there anything like this in asp.net webforms?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Request.Form` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx).

Comment: Is it possible to have an array in the request form property?